# Обернуть полученную ссылку в href гиперссылку для XMPP мессенджера

Tags: c#, бот, xmpp

Одна из функций разрабатываемого бота - на полученное слово выдавать результат поиска из местной wiki. Функционал реализован, в ответ на слово бот отправляет ссылку на Вики. Но есть необходимость сделать вид ссылки более приятный глазу (т.е. оформить в гиперссылку).
Бот написан на C#, ссылка получена через HttpWebRequest как строка. Каким образом можно полученную ссылку оформить как гиперссылку?

Примерно в таком виде ссылка выводится в мессенджере как гиперссылка:

```
<a class="object-ref-link" href="https://itop.main/pages/UI.php?operation=details&amp;class=UserRequest&amp;id=2278">R-002278</a>
```

> Не написано конкретно для какого это мессенджера (только формат
> протокола) Возможно ваш мессенджер поддерживает Markdown – Pavel Popov

Мессенджер - Pidgin

Comment: Не написано конкретно для какого это мессенджера (только формат протокола) Возможно ваш мессенджер поддерживает [Markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Comment: @PavelPopov в стандартах XMPP не предусмотрено использование Markdown

Comment: Для информации: `HttpWebRequest` [устарел](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), Microsoft рекомендует [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8). А я для парсинга полученного HTML рекомендую [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).

Comment: @andreymal Понял, спс. Я просто увидел  [это](https://sourceforge.net/p/pidgin/discussion/markdown_syntax#md_ex_links) и подумал что есть возможность

Comment: По поводу формата ссылки, отправьте с помощью того же Pidgin сообщение с гиперссылкой, отправьте и посмотрите, как он сам ее создает, затем используйте точно такой же синтаксис.

Comment: @PavelPopov XMPP просто не имеет никакого отношения к внутреннему содержанию сообщения, все внутреннее форматирование - на усмотрение мессенджера. То есть если месснджер поддерживает, то будет работать. Сам стандарт XMPP здесь имеет отношение к делу такое же как HTTP к HTML.

Comment: @PavelPopov `XMPP` - это формат `XML`, следовательно все содержимое сообщения либо должно быть экранировано, либо засунуто в CDATA. В общем, все прелести передачи данных в `XML` формате там действуют, как например в SOAP.

Comment: @aepot в стандартах XMPP предусмотрено использование XHTML, не вводите людей в заблуждение)

Comment: @andreymal А XHTML - это что? Не приведенный ли к XML стандарту HTML? [XMPP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) - _открытый, основанный на XML, свободный для использования протокол для мгновенного обмена сообщениями_